# Java to javascript communication (LiveConnect) broken recently?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, liveconnect

Look at this link:

http://www.chemaxon.com/marvin/examples/applets/sketch/chemicalterms2.html

This applet is trusted, signed etc. but I can't find configuration (OS/browser/Java) where it works...

I have:

- Ubuntu 12.04 / FF 25 / Java 1.7.0_45-b18
- Ubuntu 12.04 / Chromoum 30.0.1599.114 / Java 1.7.0_45-b18
- OSX 10.9 / FF 25 / 1.7.0_21-b12
- OSX 10.9 / Safari 7.0 (9537.71) / 1.7.0_21-b12

In all those environments I can see the same js error:

```
TypeError: document.MSketch.evaluateChemicalTerms is not a function
```

is LiveConnect broken? How can I fix it?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

LiveConnect calls are not completely broken with latest jre release(7u45-b18) and allows with annoying security popup.

> The JavaScript to Java (LiveConnect) security dialog prompt is shown once per Applet classLoader instance.
>
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html#newft

Eventually java guys may not support Live Connect call, so its good time to get rid of it.

Depending on your application logic you have to replace all your liveconnect calls with alternate logic.

Comment: Do you have any propositions on liveconnect alternatives?

Comment: create method queue on each page containing applet (put live connect calls into this queue instead of calling on applet), and have one thread in the applet that will poll for the method info and will execute the method using reflection.